# Mouse stops functioning after upgrade Ubuntu 11.10>>12.04

Tags: keyboard, mouse

After the upgrade everything works fine, but after a while the mouse cursor is moving but I cannot work wirh right- or leftclick, neither the keyboard.
I work with Logitech EX100 wireless mouse and keyboard and had no problems whatsoever in 11.10
Thanks voor reply
Kind Regards
John

Comment: Try to write in terminal: `xinput`, once before mous stops working and once after it has stopped. Please paste this info in Your post.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you confirm that its not a display freeze? (you may look at the clock applet, or if you have a video playing, that would help) If it turns out to be a display freeze, that is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/993187). you may help by adding details to it, and marking it as 'this bug affects me'

Comment: I have encountered this problem a number of times ever since I began using Ubuntu (11.04). It persisted with 11.10, and now I tried 12.04 LTS Wubi and it happened to me twice. What happens is that you're able to move the mouse cursor, but right or left clicking doesn't work. And the keyboard doesn't respond to anything. It does repond to CTRL + ALT + DELETE. That's when it asks you if you want to log out. And you can log out by left clicking. Once you've logged out, you can log back in, and the mouse and keyboard work fine, that is, until they stop working again. Please help us find a permanen

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)